# Moving Nagios Core to new server (RHEL6 to CentOS 7)

Tags: centos7, nagios, rhel6

The time has come to migrate our very,very old Nagios Core server on RHEL6 to a new CentOS 7 machine.
This old nagios server has been running for several years. 
I am wondering if all I have to copy are the contents of the `/etc/nagios` and maybe `/var/log/nagios` directories.
How do I get all the historical data as well, and where are the databases stored(if any)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How was it installed? From source? From epel? Other?

Comment: It was installed from epel, yes.

Answer (score 1):

to save your nagios installation you must save :

- the logs `/var/log/nagios` in your case, these files contains the
  historic of nagios
- the `/etc/nagios` it's your conf
- the directory which contains yours custom checks if you have
- and the `status.dat` which contains the current status of your installation

By default, nagios doesn't store nothing in a database, all is stocked in these files